# MySQL join only selected rows

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT invoices.number_formatted, SUM(invoices_elements.netto)
FROM invoices
LEFT JOIN invoices_elements ON invoices_elements_code_invoices_id = invoices_id
WHERE invoices_enable = 1
AND invoices_elements_enable = 1
GROUP BY invoices_elements_code_invoices_id
```

If table "invoices_elements" doesn't have any rows with "invoices_elements_enable = 1" this query return NULL - but i want "number formatted". So i do this:

```
SELECT SUM(netto)
FROM (invoices)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM invoices_elements WHERE invoices_elements_enable = 1) ON invoices_elements_code_invoices_id = invoices_id
WHERE invoices_enable = 1
GROUP BY invoices_elements_code_invoices_id
```

... and this of coz works. But - is better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT SUM(netto)
FROM   invoices
       LEFT JOIN invoices_elements
         ON invoices_elements_code_invoices_id = invoices_id
            AND invoices_elements_enable = 1
WHERE  invoices_enable = 1
GROUP  BY invoices_elements_code_invoices_id
```

Note the restriction `invoices_elements_enable = 1` is in the `ON` clause to avoid converting the query into an `inner join`.