# Join selected rows

Tags: mysql

First of all, i've found simular [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531560/mysql-join-only-selected-rows) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630372/join-only-for-specific-rows-where-value-matches-a-variable), but they somehow don't seem to work in my situation.

I have project of which i want to display the according video. The video link is stored in the table `fe_media` with the type `Video`. The current project also have some images, which are stored in the same table, but with the type `Image`. All these records are linked via a normalisation table.

For what i've read, my query should look like this:

```
SELECT project.id, project.title, media.type, media.link
FROM projects AS project
     LEFT JOIN norm_project_media AS norm ON norm.n_project_id = project.id
     LEFT JOIN media AS media ON media.id = norm.n_media_id 
                                 AND media.type = 'Video'
WHERE project.id = '".$item."'
```

I get all the project results, but a `NULL` on the media link. I know the `$item` value is correct and should display the video link, because when i add the line `AND media.type = 'Video'` after the `WHERE` clause, it displays the video link. The problem with this solution is that, when a certain project doesn't have a video in the `fe_media` table, nothing (not even the project data) will be displayed.

:(

**Edit:**
Fixed typo, still the same problem

Comment: Why didn't you add an extra `JOIN` to that table `fe_media`?

Comment: Add sample input data and output data to understand your question in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it

I changed the order of the `media.link` records, so the video link would be on top (above all `NULL` values) and then set a limit of 1 record, like so:

```
SELECT project.id, project.title, media.type, media.link
FROM projects AS project
     LEFT JOIN norm_project_media AS norm ON norm.n_project_id = project.id
     LEFT JOIN media AS media ON media.id = norm.n_media_id AND media.type = 'Video'
WHERE project.id = '".$item."'
ORDER BY media.link DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Maybe not the most pretty solution, but at least it works